# Using a server to send payloads to APNs

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I want to send scheduled push notifications using my server. I have already setup a system where I can connect to and send notifications using PHP. I have a MySQL table setup which has the device token, time and date to be sent at, and the message.

I was thinking of using a cron job to run the php script every minute or so but I've heard that it uses a lot of resources and if the job's overlap it can cause data loss or damage. I need to use a system that is light on system resources as I only have 512mb of RAM on the server.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: cron uses almost zero resources. it's the jobs it's running that can/will consume resources. if you don't want your jobs overlapping, then write them so that only one instance of your 'push' script can ever be executing at any given time.

Comment: How would I do that using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Crontab will not eat your resources until u run process with looping inside.

If you would like to add some php files to be runned from crontab add next line using shell command **crontab -e**

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/your.php
```

This crontab will start php script every hour.

Comment: I thought to run a cron job every minute you do * * * * * rather than 0 * * * *